# Django pagination: How do 'paginator' and 'page_obj' get injected into a template's context?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm trying to understand some source code which is used in a `ListView` to generate pagination links at the bottom of the page. For example, on a page listing 'experts', it looks like this:

[image]

It seems to be implemented somewhat differently from the way described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/. There is an inclusion tag called `paginator`:

```
from django import template
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage

from dashboard.views.utils import query_dict_from_params_or_cookies

register = template.Library()


def query_params(params):
    query = params.copy()

    if query.get('page'):
        del query['page']

    return '&' + query.urlencode() if query.urlencode() else ''


@register.inclusion_tag('templatetags/paginator.html', takes_context=True)
def paginator(context, adjacent_pages=2):
    request = context['request']

    page_obj = context['page_obj']
    page_range = context['paginator'].page_range

    page_number = page_obj.number
    last_page_number = len(page_range)

    left_idx = max(0, page_number - adjacent_pages - 1)
    right_idx = min(page_number + adjacent_pages, last_page_number)

    if left_idx == 2:
        left_idx -= 1

    if right_idx == last_page_number - 2:
        right_idx += 1

    window = page_range[left_idx:right_idx]

    try:
        previous_page_number = page_obj.previous_page_number()
    except EmptyPage:
        previous_page_number = None

    try:
        next_page_number = page_obj.next_page_number()
    except EmptyPage:
        next_page_number = None

    params = query_dict_from_params_or_cookies(request)

    return {
        'has_previous': page_obj.has_previous(),
        'has_next': page_obj.has_next(),
        'previous_page_number': previous_page_number,
        'next_page_number': next_page_number,
        'last_page_number': last_page_number,
        'page_range': window,
        'page_number': page_number,
        'show_first': page_number > adjacent_pages + 1,
        'show_left_gap': page_number > adjacent_pages + 3,
        'show_last': page_number < last_page_number - adjacent_pages,
        'show_right_gap': page_number < last_page_number - adjacent_pages - 2,
        'query_params': query_params(params)
    }
```

The corresponding template, `templatetags/paginator.html`, looks like this:

```
<ul class="pagination right"
    {% if has_previous %}data-previous-page="?page={{ previous_page_number }}{{ query_params }}"{% endif %}
    {% if has_next %}data-next-page="?page={{ next_page_number }}{{ query_params }}"{% endif %}>
  {% if has_previous %}
    <li class="waves-effect">
      <a href="?page={{ previous_page_number }}{{ query_params }}">
        <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if show_first %}
    <li><a href="?page=1{{ query_params }}">1</a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if show_left_gap %}
    <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% for i in page_range %}
    {% if page_number == i %}
      <li class="active"><a>{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?page={{ i }}{{ query_params }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if show_right_gap %}
    <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if show_last %}
    <li>
      <a href="?page={{ last_page_number }}{{ query_params }}">{{ last_page_number }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if has_next %}
    <li class="waves-effect">
      <a href="?page={{ next_page_number }}{{ query_params }}">
        <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li class="disabled">
      <a><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

What I don't quite understand is how `paginator` and `page_obj` get inserted into the template's context. For example, I did a project-wide search for `page_obj` and it does not appear that it is being injected in our own code, which would mean that it is being injected by Django's source code. But how is this being done?

Also, it seems to me like some of the logic essentially replicates what is in Django's `Paginator` class and this code could be simplified/refactored, would anyone agree?

[image]

Comment: You might find [ccbv](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) useful for exploring Django’s class based views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this is indeed done by Django's source code - specifically, by the generic [`ListView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2afa5eb2308e672b6313876856e32e2561b90f3/django/views/generic/list.py). The `get_context_data()` method of the `MultipleObjectMixin` (from which `ListView` inherits) reads:

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    """Get the context for this view."""
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_obj': page,
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'paginator': None,
            'page_obj': None,
            'is_paginated': False,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

Clearly, `paginator` and `page_obj` are added to the context here.